# How to accept just certain characters into a textbox?

Tags: c#, textbox

How do I limit textbox from accepting letter A,B,C,D only? I've tried this code, but it still accepts letters aside from letters A,B,C,D.

```
e.Handled = !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar);
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Did you consider using a ComboBox instead of a TextBox? That may suit your needs better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the `KeyPress` event of your `TextBox`, you can just use this simple code to achieve your aim:

```
if (e.KeyChar < 'A' || e.KeyChar > 'D')
    e.Handled = true;
```

If you wish to accept lower and upper case A-D:

```
if ((e.KeyChar < 'A' || e.KeyChar > 'D') && (e.KeyChar <'a' || e.KeyChar > 'd'))
    e.Handled = true;
```

If you also wish to allow 'special' characters like backspace, delete, etc., you need to also allow characters below ASCII code 32:

```
if ((e.KeyChar < 'A' || e.KeyChar > 'D') && (e.KeyChar <'a' || e.KeyChar > 'd') && e.KeyChar > 32)
    e.Handled = true;
```

Following a further user comment, in order to allow A-D, a-d and backspace only, the following should suffice:

```
if ((e.KeyChar < 'A' || e.KeyChar > 'D') && (e.KeyChar <'a' || e.KeyChar > 'd') && e.KeyChar != 8)
    e.Handled = true;
```

Comment: After I've used your code, I can't erase what I've typed. But it worked, and the textbox doesn't accept letters aside from A-D. but it can't be erased

Comment: @julianconcepcion Just add the extra check for characters below code 32: `&& e.KeyChar > 32`.  I'll edit the post to reflect this.

Comment: what if I only want backspace?

Comment: Backspace has a `KeyChar` of 8, so just change the last check from `e.KeyChar > 32` to `e.KeyChar != 8`.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the comment that if all you want is a single character that actually using a combo box may be more appropriate, but if you're planning on allowing the user to enter a series of the limited characters then it may be worth having a look at an article that I wrote a few years ago about how to restrict the characters that are allowed in the text box, which is available at "[Restrict characters entered into textbox](http://satalketo.com/2010/08/restrict-characters-entered-into-textbox/)".

Further to DanDan78's comment below the important code is;

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress

    Dim allowedChars As String = "0123456789"

    If allowedChars.IndexOf(e.KeyChar) = -1 Then
        ' Invalid Character
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is effectively a link-only answer and also borders on blog-spam. What happens when your blog disappears? The answer will be useless. Please edit it to add the basics of what is in your blog post.

Answer (score 0):

Attach a KeyPressEventHandler to the text box:

```
textBox.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(keyPressed);
```

Then create an event to handle these letters:

```
private void keyPressed(Object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == 'A' || e.KeyChar == 'B' || e.KeyChar == 'C' || e.KeyChar == 'D') 
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

This will stop the text box accepting these letters